# Cannot use Jquery with Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I do not succeed in using Jquery with Symfony.
For information I use Jquery link provided by google.

in my **twig file** I have the following lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>my title</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('/js/myjsfile.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  </head>

  <body>
     <string class="changecolor red">HELLO<string>
  </body>

</html>
```

in my **myjsfile.js** I have the following lines: ***(the file is in folders: Symfony/web/js)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $(".changecolor").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).addClass("blue");
        }
        $(".changecolor").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("blue");
            $(this).addClass("red");
        }
});
```

my css file is working fine so I do not put it here (just is .blue{color:blue};)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed events methods parenthesis. Your JavaScript code should look as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".changecolor").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).addClass("blue");
        });
        $(".changecolor").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("blue");
            $(this).addClass("red");
        });
    });
```

Why are you using so old jQuery version? Why don't you make this effect using CSS `:hover` selector?

Comment: thank you marian0. Actually I never used Jquery with Symfony and thought that the probleme was not in the javascript code but was from in the twig document. (never imported it with asset function so far so was a bit confused).

Comment: As for the css:hover selector my jquery code was just a try for me to use jquery with symfony. just wanted to do a simple code (but still I manage to forgot the parenthesis! too bad of me.

Comment: The Jquery version is one which work just fine with me... but might have to upgrade it.

Comment: An other QUESTION: why so many people seems to use a Jquery Bundle with Symfony whereas google provide a good online API. (seems to me that people using Php without Symfony use mostly that Jquery provided by google.)